# Help understanding gamma posterior of exponential likelihood

Tags: distributions, bayesian, gamma-distribution, exponential-distribution, conjugate-prior

The posterior of $\text{Exp}(x;\lambda)$ with prior $\text{Gamma}(\lambda;\alpha, \beta)$ is $\text{Gamma}(\lambda|\alpha+n, \beta + n\bar x)$ where $n$ is the number of observations and $\bar x$ is the mean of those $n$ observations.

Suppose $\alpha=1, \beta=1, n=10, \bar x=3$. Shouldn't the posterior be $\text{Gamma}(\lambda;11, 31)$?

When I [plot this in Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+gamma%281%2B10%2C+1%2B30%29&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C+%22gamma%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22ProbabilityDistribution%22%7D), I get a distribution centered around ~300 which doesn't look right? If I observe $x=3$ 10 times I expect $\lambda$ to be around $1/3$? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The gamma distribution has two common parametrizations.

Comment: What exactly do your Gamma parameters mean?  This is inherently ambiguous because at least two conventions are in use.

Comment: Indeed -- I regularly use three distinct parameterizations of the Gamma.

Comment: Is there a reference to the two parameterizations and how they transform between each other?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution.  But you don't actually need to be aware of that: for *any* distributional family you need to recognize there are infinitely many possible parameterizations and therefore, when you first use a shorthand notation for the family, you *always* ought to explain what the parameters mean; and when you read such notation on the Web, a textbook, a paper, or any other source, you shouldn't assume you know what it means: you should look for a definition.